# How does Cakephp Checks its naming conventions and folder names?

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, conventions

Where does the cakephp naming conventions (i.e controller name should be CakesController.php i.e end with Controller) and the folder conventions (i.e controller files are from app/Controller folder) **are defined** . **i.e how does cakephp check it. in which file they are defined.**

Comment: Lol. What is your question?

Comment: Do you mean where they are? Try doing a google search for "Cakephp naming convention" first

Comment: sorry for prev  incomplete question

Comment: There is a class dedicated for pluralizing and singularizing English words: http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Inflector.html

Comment: @-ComFreek , for folder names how does it use the controller file from controller folder how it checks the file from controller folder, can i use other folder name instead of controller.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of that stuff happens in the `Dispatcher` with the help of the [`Router`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) and the [`Inflector`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html), for instance:

```
protected function _loadController($request) {
    $pluginName = $pluginPath = $controller = null;
    if (!empty($request->params['plugin'])) {
        $pluginName = $controller = Inflector::camelize($request->params['plugin']);
        $pluginPath = $pluginName . '.';
    }
    if (!empty($request->params['controller'])) {
        $controller = Inflector::camelize($request->params['controller']);
    }
    if ($pluginPath . $controller) {
        $class = $controller . 'Controller';
        App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
        App::uses($pluginName . 'AppController', $pluginPath . 'Controller');
        App::uses($class, $pluginPath . 'Controller');
        if (class_exists($class)) {
            return $class;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php#L244

Also see the [CakePHP Cookbook explaining a typical request](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/a-typical-cakephp-request.html)

[image: typical CakePHP Request Lifecycle]